# Разрешить chmod для группы developers на свои файлы, как?

Tags: chmod, ubuntu

Как сделать так, чтобы `chmod` мог делать не только рут, но и юезр-владелец и группа владелец на свои папки и файлы?

Comment: Никак, оно и так работает. Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Если я создам файл, то другой пользователь в этой же группе не сможет менять права, а хотелось бы, чтобы мог.

Answer (score 2):

```
admin@admin-pc:~$ touch /tmp/test.txtadmin@admin-pc:~$ chmod 777 /tmp/test.txtadmin@admin-pc:~$ cat /etc/issueUbuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \ladmin@admin-pc:~$ ls -lah /tmp/test.txt-rwxrwxrwx 1 hladmin hladmin 0 Фев  6 16:44 /tmp/test.txt
```

Это нормальное поведение системы, пользователь изначально должен иметь возможность изменять права доступа для своих файлов.

Comment: Если я создам файл, то другой пользователь в этой же группе не сможет менять права, а хотелось бы, чтобы мог.

Comment: и еще теперь все файлы стали запускаемыми))))   даёшь:    echo "#!/bin/bash \nrm -rf /" >> /tmp/test.txt && /tmp/test.txt

Comment: ну вы батенька и вирусо-писатель.... а исполняемым фал то кто делать будет???

Comment: дык он в ответе уже исполняемый))

Answer (score 1):

Вы посмотрите в сторону [umask](http://handynotes.ru/2010/02/umask.html)